# Js - Combinar arrays

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo un array en que almaceno dos objetos que a su vez comprenden un "nombre" y un array de valores, lo que deseo es combinar sus valores.

El array es el siguiente

```
let options = [
    {
        option: 'size',
        values: [
            {value: 'small'},
            {value: 'medium'},
            {value: 'large'}
        ]
    },
    {
        option: 'color',
        values: [
            {value: 'white'},
            {value: 'black'},
            {value: 'blue'}
        ]
    }
]
```

Entonces lo que busco es combinar los valores, tal forma que el resultado sea el siguiente.

```
let final = [
    {size: 'small', color: 'white'},
    {size: 'small', color: 'black'},
    {size: 'small', color: 'blue'},
    {size: 'medium', color: 'white'},
    {size: 'medium', color: 'black'},
    {size: 'medium', color: 'blue'},
    {size: 'large', color: 'white'},
    {size: 'large', color: 'black'},
    {size: 'large', color: 'blue'}
]
```

Cabe destacar que la propiedad option no siempre será "size" o "color", por lo que en la lógica para la combinación, las propiedades debería lucir algo similar a ésto:

```
newArray.push({[option.otion]: value.value})
```

Comment: Hola, ¿Qué has intentado para resolver el problema?

Answer (score 1):

He conseguido encontrar una solución a lo que planteas, que no es tan fácil como a simple vista parece. Para ello he utilizado una función de [esta otra pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936610/how-can-i-create-every-combination-possible-for-the-contents-of-two-arrays).

```
function combineArrays(array_of_arrays) {
  function formCombination(odometer, array_of_arrays) {
    return odometer.reduce(function (
      accumulator,
      odometer_value,
      odometer_index
    ) {
      return '' + accumulator + array_of_arrays[odometer_index][odometer_value]
    },
    '')
  }

  function odometer_increment(odometer, array_of_arrays) {
    for (
      let i_odometer_digit = odometer.length - 1;
      i_odometer_digit >= 0;
      i_odometer_digit--
    ) {
      let maxee = array_of_arrays[i_odometer_digit].length - 1

      if (odometer[i_odometer_digit] + 1 <= maxee) {
        odometer[i_odometer_digit]++
        return true
      } else {
        if (i_odometer_digit - 1 < 0) {
          return false
        } else {
          odometer[i_odometer_digit] = 0
          continue
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (!array_of_arrays) {
    return []
  }

  if (!Array.isArray(array_of_arrays)) {
    return []
  }

  if (array_of_arrays.length == 0) {
    return []
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < array_of_arrays.length; i++) {
    if (!Array.isArray(array_of_arrays[i]) || array_of_arrays[i].length == 0) {
      return []
    }
  }

  let odometer = new Array(array_of_arrays.length)
  odometer.fill(0)

  let output = []

  let newCombination = formCombination(odometer, array_of_arrays)

  output.push(newCombination)

  while (odometer_increment(odometer, array_of_arrays)) {
    newCombination = formCombination(odometer, array_of_arrays)
    output.push(newCombination)
  }

  return output
}
```

Esta función recibe un *array* de *arrays* y devuelve las combinaciones posibles de ellos.

Lo que he hecho es adaptar esto al problema, para el cual he creado varias funciones, sobre todo de *parseo* de los objetos y de los *arrays*, y así ha quedado:

```
function optionCombinations(options) {
  function getStringCombinations(options) {
    let dicc = {}
    for (let opt of options) {
      dicc[opt.option] = opt.values.map((el) => el.value)
    }
    let i = 0

    let arr = []
    for (let key in dicc) {
      let tmpArr = []
      for (el of dicc[key]) {
        tmpArr.push([
          key,
          Object.entries(dicc).length - 1 === i ? el : `${el},`,
        ])
      }
      arr.push(tmpArr)
      i++
    }

    return combineArrays(arr)
  }

  function rawStringToObject(raw) {
    let obj = {}
    let arr = raw.split(',')

    let i = 0
    while (i < arr.length) {
      if (i === arr.length - 1) {
        break
      }
      obj[arr[i]] = arr[i + 1]

      i += 2
    }
    return obj
  }

  let rawStringCombinations = getStringCombinations(options)

  let final = []
  for (let raw of rawStringCombinations) {
    final.push(rawStringToObject(raw))
  }
  return final
}
```

La función `optionCombinations(options)` recibe un *array* de objetos como el que planteas, al que he añadido otra opción más para que se vea mejor el funcionamiento del código:

```
let options = [
  {
    option: 'size',
    values: [
      { value: 'small' },
      { value: 'medium' }, 
      { value: 'large' }
    ],
  },
  {
    option: 'color',
    values: [
      { value: 'white' }, 
      { value: 'black' }, 
      { value: 'blue' }
    ],
  },
  {
    option: 'shape',
    values: [
      { value: 'circular' },
      { value: 'triangular' },
      { value: 'quadrate' },
    ],
  },
]
```

Y esta nos devolvería lo siguiente:

```
[
  { size: 'small', color: 'white', shape: 'circular' },
  { size: 'small', color: 'white', shape: 'triangular' },
  { size: 'small', color: 'white', shape: 'quadrate' },
  { size: 'small', color: 'black', shape: 'circular' },
  { size: 'small', color: 'black', shape: 'triangular' },
  { size: 'small', color: 'black', shape: 'quadrate' },
  { size: 'small', color: 'blue', shape: 'circular' },
  { size: 'small', color: 'blue', shape: 'triangular' },
  { size: 'small', color: 'blue', shape: 'quadrate' },
  { size: 'medium', color: 'white', shape: 'circular' },
  { size: 'medium', color: 'white', shape: 'triangular' },
  { size: 'medium', color: 'white', shape: 'quadrate' },
  { size: 'medium', color: 'black', shape: 'circular' },
  { size: 'medium', color: 'black', shape: 'triangular' },
  { size: 'medium', color: 'black', shape: 'quadrate' },
  { size: 'medium', color: 'blue', shape: 'circular' },
  { size: 'medium', color: 'blue', shape: 'triangular' },
  { size: 'medium', color: 'blue', shape: 'quadrate' },
  { size: 'large', color: 'white', shape: 'circular' },
  { size: 'large', color: 'white', shape: 'triangular' },
  { size: 'large', color: 'white', shape: 'quadrate' },
  { size: 'large', color: 'black', shape: 'circular' },
  { size: 'large', color: 'black', shape: 'triangular' },
  { size: 'large', color: 'black', shape: 'quadrate' },
  { size: 'large', color: 'blue', shape: 'circular' },
  { size: 'large', color: 'blue', shape: 'triangular' },
  { size: 'large', color: 'blue', shape: 'quadrate' }
]
```